# RN module in Swift can not get param

Tags: swift, objective-c, react-native, react-native-modules

I am implementing my own module and I have a problem with passing params into function in swift. That function should return Promise. And it always crashes with this error

`Exception 'getPassesOf: is not a recognized Objective-C method.' was thrown while invoking getPassesOf on target RNAppleWallet with params ( DDDDtest, 5026, 5027 )`

my O-C bridge:

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNAppleWallet, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(openWallet:(NSDictionary*)config callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock))

...

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getPasses: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getPassesOf: (NSString *)test (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)

//RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getPassesOf:(NSString*)passType (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
//RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getPassesOf:(NSString *)passType resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock *)resolve reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock *)reject)


...


@end
```

important
Functions  `getRemoteSecureElementPasses`, `getRemotePaymentPasses` and `getPasses` works fine. But they don't have extra parameter
and function `getPassesOf` with pramateter test crash

`RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getPassesOf: (NSString *)test (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)`

This is an implementation in swift function `getPsses` works fine but `getPassesOf` have a problem with that param

```
...
  @objc
  func getPasses(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    let passes =  passLib.passes();
    let passesArray = convertPassesToJsonString(passes:passes)
    resolve(passesArray)
  }

  
 @objc
  func getPassesOf(_ test: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void{
    print("===================================================")
    print(test)

    resolve("cus")
  }
...
```

interesting is when I remove param `test` all works fine ... but I need it

and this is how I call it in RN `getPasses` works fine `getPassesOf` doest work:

```
...
  public async getPasses(): Promise<PassType[]> {
    const passData = await this.walletModule.getPasses();

    return passData.map(pass => JSON.parse(pass));
  }

  public async getPassesOf(passType: string): Promise<PassType[]> {
    // const passesOf = await this.walletModule.getPassesOf();
    const passesOf = await this.walletModule.getPassesOf('DDDDtest');

    return passesOf.map(pass => JSON.parse(pass));
  }
...
```

**UPDATE:**

I remove return type `-> Void` bud nothing change still doesn't work

before:

`@objc func getPassesOf(_ test: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void{`

after:

`@objc func getPassesOf(_ test: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code with definition of your `getPassesOf` function in Objective-C (missing `resolve:`) and the bridge can't find your method:

```js
// Your
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getPassesOf:(NSString *)test (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject);

// Correct
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getPassesOf:(NSString *)test resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject);
```

**Many parameters**

The common rule for `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` or `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` with many parameters:

Objective-C:

```js
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(methodName:(Type1*)param1 param2:(Type2*)param2 ... 
 paramN:(TypeN*)paramN);
```

Swift:

```swift
@objc
func methodName(_ param1: Type1, param2: Type2, ..., paramN: TypeN) {
    ...
}
```

Where types should be NSString*, NSNumber*, BOOL etc. in ObjC and String, Int, Bool etc. in Swift (https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#argument-types)

For promises you should append `resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject` in ObjC and `resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock` in Swift to the end of the parameters list accordingly.

Comment: I have another problem I can not pass two variables :D any advice?

Comment: @LukášŠálek look at my updated answer.